# Couldn't resolve host name while using solr package in R

Tags: r, solr

I am trying to query the solr server set up on machine.But I am getting the following error

```
*Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't resolve host name*
```

following is my code:

```
solrUrl<-'http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/'
solr_search(q='*:*', rows=2, fl='id', base=solrUrl)

I have also tried follwng values of URLs
http://localhost:8983
http://localhost:8983/solr/
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select/
```

PS : I could access the solr server using

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select/?q=video
```

Not sure where I am doing mistake.Any pointers will be useful

Comment: I maintain a solr client for R, `solrium`, try it out at https://github.com/ropensci/solrium

Comment: How to authenticate access for solr api? Also, please suggest on how to parse the json or csv output found embedded in HTML page?